# Выдает ошибку: "AttributeError: module 'raylib' has no attribute 'load_texture'"

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pycharm

```
import raylib as rl

# Определяем константы для размеров экрана, клеток и спрайтов
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
CELL_SIZE = 40
SPRITE_SIZE = 32

# Определяем константы для цветов
BLACK = rl.BLACK
WHITE = rl.WHITE
YELLOW = rl.YELLOW
BLUE = rl.BLUE
RED = rl.RED
PINK = rl.PINK
ORANGE = rl.ORANGE

# Определяем константы для направлений
UP = 0
RIGHT = 1
DOWN = 2
LEFT = 3

# Определяем константы для типов клеток
WALL = 0
DOT = 1
POWER = 2
EMPTY = 3

# Определяем константы для состояний игры
PLAYING = 0
GAME_OVER = 1
WIN = 2


# Создаем класс для игрового объекта
class GameObject:
    # Конструктор класса
    def __init__(self, x, y, texture, speed, direction):
        # Координаты объекта
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        # Текстура объекта
        self.texture = texture
        # Скорость объекта
        self.speed = speed
        # Направление объекта
        self.direction = direction
        # Флаг, показывающий, что объект находится в движении
        self.moving = False
        # Флаг, показывающий, что объект находится под воздействием силы
        self.powered = False
        # Таймер, отсчитывающий время действия силы
        self.power_timer = 0

    # Метод для обновления состояния объекта
    def update(self):
        # Если объект находится в движении
        if self.moving:
            # Двигаем объект в зависимости от направления
            if self.direction == UP:
                self.y -= self.speed
            elif self.direction == RIGHT:
                self.x += self.speed
            elif self.direction == DOWN:
                self.y += self.speed
            elif self.direction == LEFT:
                self.x -= self.speed
            # Проверяем, не вышел ли объект за границы экрана
            if self.x < 0:
                self.x = SCREEN_WIDTH - CELL_SIZE
            elif self.x > SCREEN_WIDTH - CELL_SIZE:
                self.x = 0
            elif self.y < 0:
                self.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - CELL_SIZE
            elif self.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT - CELL_SIZE:
                self.y = 0
            # Проверяем, не достиг ли объект центра клетки
            if self.x % CELL_SIZE == 0 and self.y % CELL_SIZE == 0:
                # Останавливаем объект
                self.moving = False
        # Если объект находится под воздействием силы
        if self.powered:
            # Уменьшаем таймер силы
            self.power_timer -= 1
            # Если таймер силы истек
            if self.power_timer == 0:
                # Снимаем воздействие силы
                self.powered = False

    # Метод для отрисовки объекта
    def draw(self):
        # Рисуем объект с помощью текстуры
        rl.draw_texture(self.texture, self.x, self.y, WHITE)


# Создаем класс для игрового поля
class GameField:
    # Конструктор класса
    def __init__(self, map_file, wall_texture, dot_texture, power_texture):
        # Текстура для стен
        self.wall_texture = wall_texture
        # Текстура для точек
        self.dot_texture = dot_texture
        # Текстура для сил
        self.power_texture = power_texture
        # Счетчик для количества собранных точек
        self.dot_count = 0
        # Счетчик для количества собранных сил
        self.power_count = 0
        # Матрица для хранения типов клеток
        self.cells = []
        # Открываем файл с картой
        with open(map_file, "r") as file:
            # Читаем строки из файла
            lines = file.readlines()
            # Проходим по строкам
            for line in lines:
                # Создаем список для хранения типов клеток в строке
                row = []
                # Проходим по символам в строке
                for char in line:
                    # Если символ - знак стены
                    if char == "#":
                        # Добавляем в список тип стены
                        row.append(WALL)
                    # Если символ - знак точки
                    elif char == ".":
                        # Добавляем в список тип точки
                        row.append(DOT)
                        # Увеличиваем счетчик точек
                        self.dot_count += 1
                    # Если символ - знак силы
                    elif char == "*":
                        # Добавляем в список тип силы
                        row.append(POWER)
                        # Увеличиваем счетчик сил
                        self.power_count += 1
                    # Если символ - знак пустоты
                    elif char == " ":
                        # Добавляем в список тип пустоты
                        row.append(EMPTY)
                # Добавляем список в матрицу
                self.cells.append(row)

    # Метод для обновления состояния поля
    def update(self, pac_man, ghosts):
        # Получаем индексы клетки, в которой находится пакман
        i = pac_man.y // CELL_SIZE
        j = pac_man.x // CELL_SIZE
        # Получаем тип клетки
        cell_type = self.cells[i][j]
        # Если клетка - точка
        if cell_type == DOT:
            # Уменьшаем счетчик точек
            self.dot_count -= 1
            # Меняем тип клетки на пустоту
            self.cells[i][j] = EMPTY
        # Если клетка - сила
        elif cell_type == POWER:
            # Уменьшаем счетчик сил
            self.power_count -= 1
            # Меняем тип клетки на пустоту
            self.cells[i][j] = EMPTY
            # Включаем воздействие силы на пакмана
            pac_man.powered = True
            # Задаем таймер силы
            pac_man.power_timer = 300
            # Включаем воздействие силы на привидений
            for ghost in ghosts:
                ghost.powered = True
                ghost.power_timer = 300

    # Метод для отрисовки поля
    def draw(self):
        # Проходим по матрице клеток
        for i in range(len(self.cells)):
            for j in range(len(self.cells[i])):
                # Получаем тип клетки
                cell_type = self.cells[i][j]
                # Получаем координаты клетки
                x = j * CELL_SIZE
                y = i * CELL_SIZE
                # Если клетка - стена
                if cell_type == WALL:
                    # Рисуем стену с помощью текстуры
                    rl.draw_texture(self.wall_texture, x, y, WHITE)
                # Если клетка - точка
                elif cell_type == DOT:
                    # Рисуем точку с помощью текстуры
                    rl.draw_texture(self.dot_texture, x + (CELL_SIZE - SPRITE_SIZE) // 2,
                                    y + (CELL_SIZE - SPRITE_SIZE) // 2, WHITE)
                # Если клетка - сила
                elif cell_type == POWER:
                    # Рисуем силу с помощью текстуры
                    rl.draw_texture(self.power_texture, x + (CELL_SIZE - SPRITE_SIZE) // 2,
                                    y + (CELL_SIZE - SPRITE_SIZE) // 2, WHITE)



# Создаем класс для игры
def draw():
    # Начинаем рисование
    rl.begin_drawing()
    # Очищаем фон
    rl.clear_background(BLACK)
    # Рисуем поле


class Game:
    # Конструктор класса
    def __init__(self):
        # Инициализируем библиотеку RayLib
        rl.init_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Pac-Man")
        rl.set_target_fps(60)
        # Загружаем текстуры для игровых объектов
        self.pac_man_texture = rl.load_texture("pac_man.png")
        self.blinky_texture = rl.load_texture("blinky.png")
        self.pinky_texture = rl.load_texture("pinky.png")
        self.inky_texture = rl.load_texture("inky.png")
        self.clyde_texture = rl.load_texture("clyde.png")
        self.wall_texture = rl.load_texture("wall.png")
        self.dot_texture = rl.load_texture("dot.png")
        self.power_texture = rl.load_texture("power.png")
        # Создаем объекты для пакмана и привидений
        self.pac_man = GameObject(360, 280, self.pac_man_texture, 2, RIGHT)
        self.blinky = GameObject(360, 240, self.blinky_texture, 2, UP)
        self.pinky = GameObject(360, 280, self.pinky_texture, 2, DOWN)
        self.inky = GameObject(320, 280, self.inky_texture, 2, LEFT)
        self.clyde = GameObject(400, 280, self.clyde_texture, 2, RIGHT)
        # Создаем список для хранения привидений
        self.ghosts = [self.blinky, self.pinky, self.inky, self.clyde]
        # Создаем объект для игрового поля
        self.field = GameField("map.txt", self.wall_texture, self.dot_texture, self.power_texture)
        # Создаем переменную для хранения состояния игры
        self.state = PLAYING

    # Метод для обновления состояния игры
    def update(self):
        # Если игра продолжается
        if self.state == PLAYING:
            # Обновляем состояние пакмана
            self.pac_man.update()
            # Обновляем состояние привидений
            for ghost in self.ghosts:
                ghost.update()
            # Обновляем состояние поля
            self.field.update(self.pac_man, self.ghosts)
            # Проверяем, не закончились ли точки и силы на поле
            if self.field.dot_count == 0 and self.field.power_count == 0:
                # Меняем состояние игры на победу
                self.state = WIN
            # Проверяем, не столкнулся ли пакман с привидением
            for ghost in self.ghosts:
                if self.pac_man.x == ghost.x and self.pac_man.y == ghost.y:
                    # Если пакман под воздействием силы
                    if self.pac_man.powered:
                        # Отправляем привидение в начальную позицию
                        ghost.x = 360
                        ghost.y = 280
                        ghost.direction = DOWN
                        ghost.moving = False
                    # Если пакман не под воздействием силы
                    else:
                        # Меняем состояние игры на проигрыш
                        self.state = GAME_OVER
            # Обрабатываем ввод пользователя
            self.handle_input()
        # Если игра окончена
        elif self.state == GAME_OVER or self.state == WIN:
            # Обрабатываем ввод пользователя
            self.handle_input()

    # Метод для обработки ввода пользователя
    def handle_input(self):
        # Если нажата клавиша вверх
        if rl.is_key_pressed(rl.KEY_UP):
            # Пытаемся повернуть пакмана вверх
            self.turn_pac_man(UP)
        # Если нажата клавиша вправо
        elif rl.is_key_pressed(rl.KEY_RIGHT):
            # Пытаемся повернуть пакмана вправо
            self.turn_pac_man(RIGHT)
        # Если нажата клавиша вниз
        elif rl.is_key_pressed(rl.KEY_DOWN):
            # Пытаемся повернуть пакмана вниз
            self.turn_pac_man(DOWN)
        # Если нажата клавиша влево
        elif rl.is_key_pressed(rl.KEY_LEFT):
            # Пытаемся повернуть пакмана влево
            self.turn_pac_man(LEFT)
        # Если нажата клавиша пробел
        elif rl.is_key_pressed(rl.KEY_SPACE):
            # Если игра окончена
            if self.state == GAME_OVER or self.state == WIN:
                # Перезапускаем игру
                self.restart()

    # Метод для поворота пакмана
    def turn_pac_man(self, direction):
        # Если пакман не движется
        if not self.pac_man.moving:
            # Меняем направление пакмана
            self.pac_man.direction = direction
            # Проверяем, не столкнется ли пакман со стеной
            if not self.check_collision(self.pac_man):
                # Запускаем движение пакмана
                self.pac_man.moving = True
        # Если пакман движется
        else:
            # Запоминаем текущее направление пакмана
            old_direction = self.pac_man.direction
            # Меняем направление пакмана
            self.pac_man.direction = direction
            # Проверяем, не столкнется ли пакман со стеной
            if not self.check_collision(self.pac_man):
                # Запускаем движение пакмана
                self.pac_man.moving = True
            # Если столкнется
            else:
                # Возвращаем прежнее направление пакмана
                self.pac_man.direction = old_direction

    # Метод для проверки столкновения объекта со стеной
    def check_collision(self, obj):
        # Получаем индексы клетки, в которой находится объект
        i = obj.y // CELL_SIZE
        j = obj.x // CELL_SIZE
        # Получаем тип клетки
        cell_type = self.field.cells[i][j]
        # Если клетка - стена
        if cell_type == WALL:
            # Возвращаем истину
            return True
        # Если клетка - не стена
        else:
            # Возвращаем ложь
            return False

    # Метод для перезапуска игры
    def restart(self):
        # Возвращаем пакмана и привидений в начальные позиции
        self.pac_man.x = 360
        self.pac_man.y = 280
        self.pac_man.direction = RIGHT
        self.pac_man.moving = False
        self.pac_man.powered = False
        self.pac_man.power_timer = 0
        self.blinky.x = 360
        self.blinky.y = 240
        self.blinky.direction = UP
        self.blinky.moving = False
        self.blinky.powered = False
        self.blinky.power_timer = 0
        self.pinky.x = 360
        self.pinky.y = 280
        self.pinky.direction = DOWN
        self.pinky.moving = False
        self.pinky.powered = False
        self.pinky.power_timer = 0
        self.inky.x = 320
        self.inky.y = 280
        self.inky.direction = LEFT
        self.inky.moving = False
        self.inky.powered = False
        self.inky.power_timer = 0
        self.clyde.x = 400
        self.clyde.y = 280
        self.clyde.direction = RIGHT
        self.clyde.moving = False
        self.clyde.powered = False
        self.clyde.power_timer = 0
        # Восстанавливаем точки и силы на поле
        self.field = GameField("map.txt", self.wall_texture, self.dot_texture, self.power_texture)
        # Меняем состояние игры на продолжение
        self.state = PLAYING


def main():
    pac_man_texture = rl.load_texture("pac_man.png")
    ghost_texture = rl.load_texture("ghost.png")
    wall_texture = rl.load_texture("wall.png")
    dot_texture = rl.load_texture("dot.png")
    power_texture = rl.load_texture("power.png")
    while not rl.window_should_close():


        pac_man = GameObject(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2, pac_man_texture, 2, RIGHT)
        ghosts = [GameObject(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2, ghost_texture, 1, LEFT)]
        game_field = GameField("map.txt", wall_texture, dot_texture, power_texture)
        pac_man.update()
        for ghost in ghosts:
            ghost.update()
        game_field.update(pac_man, ghosts)

        # Рисование
        rl.begin_drawing()
        rl.clear_background(BLACK)
        pac_man.draw()
        for ghost in ghosts:
            ghost.draw()
        game_field.draw()
        rl.end_drawing()



    # Очистка
    rl.unload_texture(pac_man_texture)
    rl.unload_texture(ghost_texture)
    rl.unload_texture(wall_texture)
    rl.unload_texture(dot_texture)
    rl.unload_texture(power_texture)
    rl.close_window()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```